# Using win32com and python 3.7.2 64bit to connect to MS Excel 2016 32bit

Tags: excel, python-3.x, vba, pywin32, win32com

I would like to know, if it is possible to use win32com library (win32com.client and others) to connect to MS Excell with Python in following configuration:

MS Excel 2016 32bit

Python 3.7.4 64bit

Win10 64bit

win32com (I dont know how its architecture is defined)

I have already read this question and its answer: [Python win32com - application installed with both 32bit and 64bit versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937060/python-win32com-application-installed-with-both-32bit-and-64bit-versions)

and also have scoured google and found, that it is connected to .dll libraries being unable to cope with difference in architecture, but it is still not entirely clear to me. I have also installed 64bit ODBC drivers for MS Access connection (to connect to 32bit Access with 64bit Python, and this connection works), which should also include libraries to connect to MS Excell, but I still cant use win32com.client to create COM objects in Excel.

Note: I also have access to following configuration:

MS Excell 2010 32bit

Python 3.7.2 32bit

Win7 32bit

win32com

In which the connection works (more or less).

Comment: This what you are looking for https://www.xlwings.org/ ?

Comment: Maybe, but I think not exactly. My ultimate goal is to be able to create Excel PivotTable (dont confuse with pandas pivot_table function!) and PivotChart from python script.

Comment: I don't know about PivotTables, but xlwings gives you a pretty strong Excel-API. If your goal is to make a chart, why do you need it to be in Excel?

Comment: The goal is more like to have both Chart and Table interactive and sychronized together; and also being able to add them to .pdf as attachment. I dont know of any other way to achieve that specific with any other application than Excel.